# MVC4 Conditional Required Annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I  have a property which is set to required via data annotation. This works perfectly fine for the create form but I would like to make the property not required in the edit form. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Use a seperate model for your edit form.  That's what View Models are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create seperate view models for create and edit views. You can keep the common properties in a common class and inherit those 2 view models from that common class.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{      
  public string Name { set;get;}      
  public string Location { set;get;}      
}
public class CreateCustomer :CustomerViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string LastJobTitle { set;get;}
}
public class EditCustomer :CustomerViewModel
{  
  public string LastJobTitle { set;get;}
}
```

And you can use these in your Action method like this

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var createVM=new CreateCustomer();
  return View(createVM);
}
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var editVM=new EditCustomer();
  var customerModel=repositary.GetCustomer(id);
  editVM.LastJobTitle=customerModel.LastJobTitle;
  //set other properties also
  return View(createVM);
}
```

So your create view will be strongly typed to `CreateCustomer` class and edit view will be strongly typed to `EditCustomer` class.

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model CreateCustomer
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@model EditCustomer
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought too but I since I am using code first and my entities are in the data project, I was trying to use those directly from the web project (maybe the wrong approach). What is the best practice in mapping these WebViewModels to the entities in the data project, if there is any?

Comment: You can manually map (like i did in Edit view or use a library like Automapper)