# Conditional required data annotation with EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, data-annotations

We have a ViewModel for "create" and one for "edit." The edit inherits from create so that we're sharing common fields.  We are then using an @Html.EditorForModel("User") that uses the "create" as its model.

This is for editing users, so I need the password field to be required on create, but not required on delete. Thus, the create VM has Password with [Required] decorating it, while the edit VM has password property with no decoration, and is also declared with new (public new string Password {get;set;}).

This is almost exactly similar to this question:
[MVC4 Conditional Required Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186510/mvc4-conditional-required-annotation)

For my situation, it's still requiring the field I believe due to the EditorTemplate using the create object as its model instead of the edit.  I tried changing it from editorformodel to:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model, "User")
```

in hopes that because edit is actually a "create" due to inheritance that it would work, but it'still barking at me for not providing the required field when I post.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm attempting, or are my options to either remove the required and handle it server-side, or split the editor template into two templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom attribute to drive your check on whether the password is required or not. When the submission happens to the server your custom attribute can check to see if the you are dealing with an Update or and Insert and then invalidate the model if it needs to.

Here are some resources on creating [custom attributes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2933/Attributes-in-C) and [custom attributes with unobstrusive jquery validation](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/)

Happy Coding!!

Comment: This is probably the way to go...just have to figure out a way to determine if it's an edit or create while inside of that attribute

Comment: @tjans since you are inheriting from the create class you can create a property in your create class and have a constructor set the value for that property. This way when Update inherits from create it can set the value of that particular proerty to "Edit." Otherwise the value of the property remains as "Create." Then your custom required attribute for your password field can check that to determine if password is required or not.

Comment: That is precisely how I started to code it, and then after I bounced my idea off of one of my colleagues, we settled on the attribute being "RequiredIfRouteName" and we'll only require it for the given route, though getting the route name might not be possible within the attribute.